# Agrupar Registros Duplicados con Diferentes Valores en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

El marco de datos original contiene registros de Id_cliente repetidos con diferente información en las columnas Cantidad, Marca y Talla que incluyen registros nulos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado deseado; es agrupar los registros repetidos y consolidar en una sola fila la información que contienen el resto de las filas en Id_Cliente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se utilizó primeramente la sig. línea sin obtener resultados favorables;

```
df=df.groupby[('Id_Cliente')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tu ejemplo es representativo de tus datos reales puedes conseguir lo que quieres con [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html), que básicamente toma por cada grupo el primer valor no nulo de cada columna.

Con representativo me refiero a que en tus datos reales **no exista la posibilidad de que para un mismo valor de `Id_Cliente` alguna de las otras columnas tengan más de un valor no nulo**.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"Id_Cliente": (1001, 1001, 1001, 2002, 2002, 2002, 3003, 3003, 3003, 4004, 4004, 4004),
                   "Cantidad": (200, None, None, 400, None, None, 600, None, None, 800, None, None),
                   "Marca": (None, "Adidas", None, None, "Nike", None, None, "Reebok", None, None, "Fila", None),
                   "Talla": (None, None, "Mediana", None, None, "Chica", None, None, "Grande", None, None, "Extragrande")
                   })
df.fillna(value=pd.np.nan, inplace=True)

df_group = df.groupby('Id_Cliente').first()
```

con lo que obtienes:

> ```
> >>> df_group
>
>             Cantidad   Marca        Talla
> Id_Cliente                               
> 1001           200.0  Adidas      Mediana
> 2002           400.0    Nike        Chica
> 3003           600.0  Reebok       Grande
> 4004           800.0    Fila  Extragrande
> ```

Si no quieres que `Id_cliente` sea el indice, basta con usar `reset_index`:

> ```
> >>> df_group.reset_index(inplace=True)
> >>> df_group
>
>    Id_Cliente  Cantidad   Marca        Talla
> 0        1001     200.0  Adidas      Mediana
> 1        2002     400.0    Nike        Chica
> 2        3003     600.0  Reebok       Grande
> 3        4004     800.0    Fila  Extragrande
> ```